# Php strtotime adds extra time to result

Tags: php, date, time

```
$date1 = strtotime('07/04/2018 13:00:00');
$date2 = mktime(13,00,00,07,04,2018);

echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s',$date1); //Result: 04-07-2018 13:07:00
echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s',$date2);//Result: 04-07-2018 13:07:00
```

I've tried all i could but the program keeps adding extra time to the output.
How can i get this program to produce the correct time (13:00:00 instead of 13:07:00 ) ?

Comment: Use `i` for minute, `m` is month. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks! I didn't test to see if you're correct but am 101% sure you're correct, its been a while i used php..... Thanks!